# Find the 27th derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f^{\left(n\right)}\left(a\right)$ denote the n-th derivative of $f$ at $a$. If $f\left(x\right)=\left(1+x^2\right)^{15}$, then $f^{\left(27\right)}\left(1\right)\:=$?

Hints appreciated!

Comment: I would write out the binomial expansion of your expression and differentiate that. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 4):

HINT:
write the last 2 terms of a binomial expansion because for any $power<26$ $f^{(27)}=0$

Comment: Can you expand on that please

Comment: Just like the other answer explained if you still stuck let me know i will explain

Comment: Still stuck. I understand of ther will be four term x^27 - X^30 but how do i use that

Comment: HI There is another answer there with much explanation hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** We know that if you differentiate $x^2$ more than 2 times, you'll get zero. In the same way, if you write out the binomial expansion for what you have here, you'll only have to worry about a maximum of 4 terms - the $x^{27}$,$x^{28}$,$x^{29}$, and $x^{30}$ terms (because $\left(x^{15}\right)^2=x^{30}$).

Answer (score 0):

Directly, using Newton's Binom:

$$f(x)=(1+x^2)^{15}=\sum_{k=0}^{15}\binom{15}kx^{2k}\implies$$

$$\begin{align}&f'(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{15}\binom{15}k2kx^{2k-1}\\
&f''(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{15}\binom{15}k2k(2k-1)x^{2k-2}\\&\ldots\ldots\\
&f^{(27)}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{15}\binom{15}k2k(2k-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(2k-26)x^{2k-27}\end{align}\implies$$

$$f^{(27)}(1)=\sum_{k=0}^{15}\binom{15}k2k(2k-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(2k-26)\stackrel{0\le k\le13\implies\;\text{the sum vanishes}}=$$

$$=28\cdot27\cdot\ldots\cdot2+30\cdot29\cdot\ldots\cdot4=28!+\frac{30!}{3!}$$

$$=$$